# For how much time are fumes from freshly polished wood furniture toxic and must be aired out & presence avoided?

Tags: finishing, wood, finish-selection, refinishing

PS: If needs to be in the DIY SE rather than Woodwork SE please moderators figure where it will get better responses and fit. Thanks.

PPS: Found this similar - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80922/how-best-to-remove-fumes-after-applying-polyurethane-in-a-hardwood-refinishing-p  but was hoping for better guidance if there exists on WW SE.

For how much time are fumes from freshly polished wood furniture toxic and must be aired out & presence avoided?

- Been reading about short term & long term effects of toxic chemicals in wood polish process
- Different effects of these chemicals based on eye, skin contact or fumes inhalation

What's the time duration short term after Wood Polishing that the fumes or skin contact must be avoided?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm voting to close as this cannot be answered. because toxicity of anything is related to exposure — "the dose determines the poison" — and in finishing that is directly tied to the amount of finish being used, the frequency of use, air flow and ventilation, *none of which we know*. Now while you shouldn't ignore the risks of course do be aware that most consumer-level finishes aren't *that* toxic to begin with, so there's no reason to be overly concerned unless you have a pre-existing health condition.

Comment: @Graphus - PPS: Found this similar - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80922/how-best-to-remove-fumes-after-applying-polyurethane-in-a-hardwood-refinishing-p  but was hoping for better guidance if there exists on WW SE.  

Why is the "dose poison" thing so much like a Rocket Launch for this? General Guidance for Home wood Polishing?

Comment: Are you asking about finishing or polishing? Frankly, I don' t know of any available furniture polish which has harmful fumes assuming normal ventilation.

Comment: To put it another way: An article about how to effectively avoid the health hazards of all finishes applied to all objects would be too broad.  You need to be much more specific.

Comment: The general guidance is already out there, some of it is included in the instructions printed on the labels/containers. The thing is though this ALWAYS comes down to the amount the user is exposed to — this is why occupational exposure (exposure over time with regular use) and one-time exposure are both studied and limits set by regulatory bodies. But to reiterate a point above in a different way, *most* consumer products are safe enough that *most* consumers don't have any reason to fear using them as they are not likely to get poisoned or have toxic effects if used sensibly, *as directed*.